# Ctags integration with CEDET/semantic

Tags: emacs, cscope, cedet

I have setup my Emacs(v 23.3) with CEDET 1.1 using info found in http://cedet.sourceforge.net/ and the article by Alex Ott (http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html)

I've got most of the kinks worked out to my linking with respect to my init.el file.

Now for the problem. I build TAGS myself, so there is a TAGS file in the root of my project.
However semantic doesn't seem to want to use that file and barfs with the following errors:

`` Source file `/users/lshvarts/.emacs.d/cedet-1.1/semantic/ctags/semantic-ectag-util.el' newer than byte-compiled file

Exuberent CTags not found.  Found ctags that comes with Emacs

semantic-ectag-test-version: Exuberent CTags not found.  Use M-x semantic-ectag-version RET

Exuberent CTags not found.  Use M-x semantic-ectag-version RET

Exuberent CTags not found.  Found ctags that comes with Emacs ``

Etags that I have might not be the newest version, but I am puzzled why it plainly refuses to work with it.


`boxy:92> etags --version 

etags (GNU Emacs 20.7)

Copyright (C) 1996 Free Software Foundation, Inc. and Ken Arnold

This program is distributed under the same terms as Emacs

boxy:93>`

Any help/insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need not the `etags`, but **Exuberent CTags**! You can install it from your linux/mac repository (usually it has name `ectags`, or `exuberant-ctags` on Debian), or from [it's site](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: That's a bummer - no root access on my dev machine and no ectags there. Maybe I could talk some sense into out IT guys.

Comment: why not install it into your home directory, and set `semantic-ectags-program` variable (via `M-x customize-variable`) to new location? It should work without problems

Comment: The problem is then untangling all the dependencies - the kernel version is also pretty old on the machine. I tried that once and just gave up at that stage.

Comment: why not build ectags from source code? I think that it should compile on old kernels

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly related to the problem you had, but I got the same error (Exuberent CTags not found. Use M-x semantic-ectag-version RET) after upgrading to ubuntu 12.04.

The problem was that ctags-exuberant --version returned a non numerical version:

```
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Nov  9 2011, 17:40:39
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

Just replace regex

```
"Exuberant Ctags \\([0-9.]+\\),"
```

by

```
"Exuberant Ctags \\([0-9.]+\\)[~,]"
```

in semantic-ectag-version (in semantic-ectag-util.el) and recompile the file.

Comment: which version of CEDET are you using? I believe, that this was fixed in 1.1 release...